# R: Counting Number of Observations in Each Percentile

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
country <- sample(c("USA", "Canada", "UK"), n, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("M", "F"), n, replace = TRUE)
age <- sample(18:100, n, replace = TRUE)
height <- runif(n, min = 150, max = 180)
owns_bicycle <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
```

**My Problem:**

- First, I want to break height into 3 equal sized groups by value of their height (e.g. 0%-33%, 33%-66%,66%-99%)
- Next, I want to break age into 5 equal sized groups by value of their age (e.g. 0%-20%, 20%-40%, etc.)
- Then, for each unique combination of country, gender, age_group and height_group, I want to find out the percent of who own a bicycle.

As a result, this type of analysis would let me know things like - "if you are a man between  ages 30-35, between 150-155 cm and from USA, there is a 43% chance you own a bicycle".

Here is my current attempt to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(height_group = ntile(height, 3),
         age_group = ntile(age, 5)) %>%
  group_by(country, gender, height_group, age_group) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            min_height = min(height),
            max_height = max(height),
            min_age = min(age),
            max_age = max(age),
            percent_own_bicycle = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes") * 100) %>%
  mutate(height_range = paste0(round(min_height, 1), "-", round(max_height, 1)),
         age_range = paste0(min_age, "-", max_age)) %>%
  select(-min_height, -max_height, -min_age, -max_age)
```

When I look at the results:

```
# A tibble: 62 x 8
# Groups:   country, gender, height_group [18]
   country gender height_group age_group count percent_own_bicycle height_range age_range
   <chr>   <chr>         <int>     <int> <int>               <dbl> <chr>        <chr>    
 1 Canada  F                 1         1     2                 0   157.2-158.5  23-30    
 2 Canada  F                 1         2     4                25   150.8-154.1  37-43    
 3 Canada  F                 1         4     2                 0   154.4-156.9  66-72    
 4 Canada  F                 1         5     1                 0   154.6-154.6  80-80    
 5 Canada  F                 2         1     1                 0   169.3-169.3  23-23
```

I see height_group = 1 having multiple ranges, e.g. 157.2-158.5 and 150.8-154.1 . How is this possible - I would have thought that height_group = 1 can only have a single range?

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong**

Thanks!

Comment: equal size or ranges of equal length?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

OP here - this is my second attempt:

```
final = df %>%
  mutate(height_group = cut(height, breaks = 3),
         age_group = cut(age, breaks = 5)) %>%
  group_by(country, gender, height_group, age_group) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            percent_own_bicycle = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes") * 100)
```

I think the results look more "consistent" now? (e.g. no multiple ranges)

```
  `summarise()` has grouped output by 'country', 'gender', 'height_group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 60 x 6
# Groups:   country, gender, height_group [18]
   country gender height_group age_group   count percent_own_bicycle
   <chr>   <chr>  <fct>        <fct>       <int>               <dbl>
 1 Canada  F      (151,161]    (17.9,34.2]     2                   0
 2 Canada  F      (151,161]    (34.2,50.4]     5                  40
 3 Canada  F      (151,161]    (50.4,66.6]     1                   0
 4 Canada  F      (151,161]    (66.6,82.8]     2                   0
 5 Canada  F      (151,161]    (82.8,99.1]     1                   0
 6 Canada  F      (161,170]    (17.9,34.2]     1                   0
 7 Canada  F      (161,170]    (34.2,50.4]     1                 100
 8 Canada  F      (161,170]    (50.4,66.6]     1                   0
 9 Canada  F      (161,170]    (82.8,99.1]     2                  50
10 Canada  F      (170,180]    (17.9,34.2]     3                   0
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Hello! I wonder why I was downvoted?

Comment: This answer was downvoted probably because it includes two followup questions and asks for further clarifications, therefore it is not an actual answer as per SO guidelines. It looks like all this content should be incorporated into the actual question with an edit, rather then as a standalone answer

Comment: ok! can you please vote to close my question? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your attempt looks correct. You have divided the `height` variable into three equal-sized groups using the `ntile()` function, and the `age` variable into five equal-sized groups. Then, you grouped the data by `country`, `gender`, `height_group`, and `age_group` and calculated the count, minimum height, maximum height, minimum age, maximum age, and the percentage of individuals who own a bicycle within each group.